# Selenium how to test a website that shortens url

Tags: testing, selenium-webdriver, automation

I am new to the automation test and I would like to know how we can pass the appropriate url for a website that shortens it url?

Comment: Please elaborate the question more with an example. It is unclear.

Answer (score 0):

There are few sites which shortens URL for you. you can use that shortened URL in your testing.
for example bit.ly